# Detecting the beginning and the end of a user input voice in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, voice

I have a flutter app in which I record the user audio. I want to use a voice activity detection model on the input audio before sending it to my apps backend. the goal is to delete unwanted data from the beginning and the end of the audio file. How can I do that?

I searched a lot on the internet but did not find any related flutter packages for voice activity detection in flutter